# Connecting PHP code to Microsoft Outlook to send email?

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

My current situation is

1. I'm using XAMPP (Localhost)
2. all outgoing ports are blocked (gmail 25,465,587, hotmail etc etc)

I want to use PHP to connect to my own microsoft outlook so I can send email from my company email address. Please help if possible, thank you!

Do i need Mercury Server to configure also since I am connecting to microsoft outlook to send email out?

Comment: Yes i agree. It's exchange. I've it, how'd i go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can connect directly to Outlook.
For me the next code works just out of the box:

```
<?php
    $subject="This is a test message";        
    $message="This is a Body Section now.....! :)";        
    $to="someaddress@somedomain.com";

    // starting outlook        
    com_load_typelib("outlook.application"); 

    if (!defined("olMailItem")) {define("olMailItem",0);}

    $outlook_Obj = new COM("outlook.application") or die("Unable to start Outlook");

    //just to check you are connected.        
    echo "Loaded MS Outlook, version {$outlook_Obj->Version}\n";        
    $oMsg = $outlook_Obj->CreateItem(olMailItem);        
    $oMsg->Recipients->Add($to);
    $oMsg->Subject=$subject;        
    $oMsg->Body=$message;        
    $oMsg->Save();        
    $oMsg->Send();    
?>
```

Please, ensure that you have added

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

at the end of php.ini (In my case I have PHP 5.3)

Comment: does it work in server ? or is this only for localhost ?

Comment: It didn't work in server for me. Was anyone able to get this working in server?

Comment: Sorry, haven't been here for thousand years. In that time I checked it only in localhost. Then I used it successfully in a virtual machine in the local network, which was used as a "server" with Windows 10 and outlook running under my profile.

Answer (score 1):

You dont connect to Outlook with PHP you connect to a mail server... In this case i suspect that would be Exchange. You can use a package like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) to send messages via SMTP with an account. So you could use the same credentials and settings that you would use for your outlook mailbox... specifically: SMTP server (outgoing server), Port, Encryption (ssl/tls) username, password.

Examples from documentation

1. [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#smtp-with-a-username-and-password)
2. [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp)
3. [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.sending.html)

Comment: I did try PHPMailer, I did set my SMTP server, port, username and password, it does not work..

Comment: What about security? Does are you guys using encryption like SSL, or TLS? Im no windows admin, but there may also be a security policy that is still going to prevent you from sending in this fashion. However, if you can connect to say GMail you could always send from that.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, when i try to telnet smtp.gmail.com as shown above, all of the ports doesn't work. I guessed it got rejected. I got my own company's SMTP server address and when i telnet (server) 25, it worked. So now I am trying to find out how to get a way about it so I can send email using PHP

Comment: Well you have to use TLS with google so you need to specify that. Also youll need to make sure you have the ssl extension installed and enabled. I would recommend working with GMail for the time being because unless you verify all the settings and have confirmed that policy is going to allow you to connect with php then no one is really going to be able to help you - whereas with gmail the settings are public and we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi prodigitalson, first of all, thank you. I've tried gmail phpmailer, it stated that the email itself was sent but when i checked my gmail account it did not state otherwise - there was no email received.

Comment: did you check your spam?

Comment: Yes i did check, there was nothing.